# Taking lot of time to open a workbook

Tags: java, excel, optimization, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to read a excel file(xlsm as have macros) everything seem to be correct but somehow code taking lot of time to execute. Here is my code:

```
public Map<String, ReportParameter> getParameters(String excelFileName) {

        File excelFile = new File(repo.getRepositoryPath() + File.separator + excelFileName);
        try (FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document)) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("parametre");
            Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();

            int pos = 1;
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
                if(cell == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                indexMap.put(cell.getStringCellValue(), pos++);
                resultMap.put(cell.getStringCellValue(), row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

            }

            return convertParameterTypesToReportParameters(resultMap, indexMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I also try to use OPCPackage but have same result. Can someone give me suggestion why it is taking lot of time and is there anything which can improve performance.

Comment: First determine what exactly takes the long time. If even creating the `XSSFWorkbook` using `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document)` takes too long, then there are not much options for optimizing. Since you seems only need reading, maybe [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) is faster.

Comment: Yes creating a XSSFWorkbook() instance taking a lot of time. Excel Streaming Reader seems to be interesting i will try with that as not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sub test()

Dim x as long, y as int 
'all of your Dims here


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'
'
'your code here
'
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

end sub
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand properly. Do you mean in before start reading and after end  i need to use these ?

Comment: After reading more about "Application.ScreenUpdating", well i don't think so this is a case because there is no screen updating involve when POI read an excel file programmatically.